# IAM Policy to only allowing viewing and editing EC2 instances by group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, aws-iam-policy

I am trying to create a IAM User Group with a policy so that these users can only view and edit EC2 instances with a specific tag associated. I was able to create the IAM policy however, all EC2 instances are being listed (dont want this) when I log as the IAM user from this group.

1. I want only the group of EC2 instances to show that are editable by an IAM user in this user group.
   Below is the JSON of the policy

```
    {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:*",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "ec2:ResourceTag/aws:autoscaling:groupName": "abcd"
                }
            }
        },
      }
```

Comment: It's not possible to list a subset of the EC2 instances.

Comment: What do you mean by "edit EC2 instances"? Which specific actions would they be performing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Actions, resources, and condition keys for Amazon EC2 - Service Authorization Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonec2.html), the `DescribeInstances` action only accepts `ec2:Region` as a Condition Key.

Therefore, a Tag cannot be used as a Condition when listing Amazon EC2 instances.